# Passing a class variable to BeautifulSoup find_all()

Tags: python, class, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

When I try to pass a class string variable to BeautifulSoup's find_all method I get an empty list. What I expected was a list of links from the website.

If I enter the identical string manual into the methods arguments I do get the desired result, the website links.

When I print() the class string variable it is identical to the string I enter manually.

Code is below.

#**Code to create an instance of class ds_gui**

#**"'a', href=True" is the class variable in question**

```
import ds_gui


wiki_links = ds_gui.search_win('https://sendgrid.com', 'Window name', 'Results title', "'a', href=True")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    wiki_links.gui.mainloop()
```

#**The class that is imported to the above code (self.criteria contains the variable in question):**

```
import tkinter as tk
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class search_win:
    '''class to create entire window'''
    def __init__(self, url, title, result_title, criteria):
        self.url = url
        self.title = title
        self.result_title = result_title
        self.criteria = criteria

        '''creating GUI below'''
        self.gui = self.win_root()
        self.url_return = self.url_box()
        self.result_widget = self.results_box()
        self.submit_button = self.submit_button()
        
        
    def scrape_page(self):
        '''data scraping function
        argument url is the url to scrape
        argument all_or_one can be 'all' or 'one'. if it is 'all' it will find all copies of the criteria. 
        'one' finds only one instance of the criteria
        argument criteria is the string to scrape
        argument results is the gui widget where the results will be displayed
        '''
        
        #open url and scrape
        try: 
            self.result_widget.delete('1.0', 'end')            
            page = urlopen(self.url_return.get())
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser') 
            result = soup.find_all(self.criteria)
            
        except (NameError, ValueError):
            result = 'invalid url'
            print(result)
        finally:
            for res in result:
                final_res = (res.string)                
                if final_res == None:
                    self.result_widget.insert('end', 'NO DATA\n')
                else:                
                    self.result_widget.insert('end', final_res + '\n')
            
            self.save_to_file()

        
    def save_to_file(self):
        
        filename = self.url_return.get()[8:] + '_data_scrape(' + str(self.criteria) + ')'
        file2 = filename.replace('/', '_')
        file3 = file2.replace('.', '_')
        file = file3 + ('.txt')
        
        try:
            with open(file, 'w') as filename_:
                filename_.write(self.result_widget.get('1.0', 'end')) 
        except:
            print('failed to save')   
    
    def win_root(self):
        '''main window'''
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.title(self.title)
        root.geometry('750x600')
        return(root)
    
    def url_box(self):
        '''box label'''
        url_label = tk.Label(self.gui, text='Enter the URL: ')
        url_label.grid(row=0,  column=0,  stick=tk.W)
        #url box
        url_entry = tk.Entry(width=70)
        url_entry.grid(row=1,   column=0,  stick=tk.W)
        url_entry.insert('0',  self.url)
        return url_entry
    
    def results_box(self):
        '''box label'''
        results_label = tk.Label(self.gui,  text='Results:')
        results_label.grid(row=2,  column=0,  stick=tk.W)
        #results_box
        scroller = tk.Scrollbar(self.gui, orient='vertical', width=18)
        scroller.grid(row=3, column=1, stick='ns')                
        results = tk.Text(self.gui,  height=20, yscrollcommand = scroller.set)     
        scroller.config(command=results.yview)
        results.grid(row=3,  column=0,  stick=tk.W)

        return results
    
    def submit_button(self):
        '''submit button'''
        submit_button = tk.Button(self.gui,  text='Submit',  command=lambda: self.scrape_page())
        submit_button.grid(row=1,  column=2,  stick=tk.W)
```

Comment: Are you trying to use find_all like this? `soup.find_all('a', href=True)`. If so, passing the string `"'a', href=True"` won't do the same thing. You'd need to use *args and **kwargs to pass these `a` as a positional argument and `href=True` as a keyword argument

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest breaking the criteria in to two separate function arguments. One for the tag critera and another for the attribute criteria rather than trying to pass both as a string.

```
tag_criteria = 'a'
attribute_criteria = {'href':'True'}

soup.find_all(tag_criteria,**attribute_criteria)
```

The ** will expand the dictionary out as keyword arguments to pass to `find_all`